# How to install multiple versions (5.5.xx and 5.7) of MySQL in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, mysql

I want to use MySQL multi version(5.5.xx and 5.7) in my desktop.

I installed mysql 5.7 using apt-get

> sudo apt-get mysql-server mysql-client

How to install mysql 5.5 and run multi mysql version?

Answer (score 4):

Install the 2nd one either from [a snap install](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-snap) or from [source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/source-installation.html).

1 of the 2 installs needs to be told to Listen to another port than the default 3306 (stop mysql, add in `my.cnf` the line `port = 3333` and start mysql).

Commands send to that changed version will need to point to port 3333.

Comment: I already installed mysql 5.7, (sudo apt-get mysql-server mysql-client). I don't understand your comment. Are you telling me to completely remove mysql and reinstall using source?

Comment: No? "Install the 2nd one from snap or source"... means you end up with 2 mysqls. One regular from apt and one from either a snap or a source. Those 2 do not conflict with apt. 2 installs of mysql from apt do conflict (ie. you can not use apt to install mysql and mariadb (a open source clone of mysql))